# svg not getting displayed on page

Tags: css, svg

[image]

I am trying to show an svg icon on my React page however it doesn't get displayed.

my svg is as follows:

```html
<svg width="48" height="48" viewBox="0 0 48 48" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><title>8B0FDD24-F4B1-4079-852B-2A7A09470E5C</title><path d="M24 28l6-8H18z" fill="#FFFFFF" fill-rule="evenodd"/></svg>
```

Please help

CSS of the parent:

```
  .MyOrders-divTableCell {
    background-color: #53606b;
    font-family: Open Sans,arial,sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-style: normal;
    font-stretch: normal;
    line-height: 1.5;
    letter-spacing: normal;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.MyOrders-sortIconLight {
    display: inline-block;
    background: url(/static-account/images/triangle-date-down-light.svg);
    height: 48px;
    width: 48px;
    float: right;
    margin-top: -14px;
    position: absolute;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Comment: Is it because it's white on white? `fill="#FFFFFF"`

Comment: @Eruant Nope my icon needs to be displayed next to Date

Comment: Okay, it's hard to tell from screen shot. Does the parent item have a `position: relative` (I can see it's absolutely positioned)?

Comment: @Eruant added CSS

Comment: What about the parent item?

Comment: Generally `position: absolute` goes with `right:0`, not with `float`.

Comment: @Eruant Added both the css

Comment: Try adding `position: relative` to the parent item. Or removing `position: absolute` from item.

Comment: @Eruant Tried that doesn't work

Comment: I would add an outline to make sure that the div is rendering where you expect `outline: solid 1px red`

Comment: Yes it renders.. https://ibb.co/egu2Mk @Eruant

Comment: I can't see the top of the outline. Could it be that the svg is out of view? Other than that I can't think of anything else to suggest.